# Remote debugging with pydev > pydevd > "connection refused". Why?

Tags: python, debug

I'm trying to have remote debugging working in Eclipse (actually Aptana 3).

I'm using the same computer both for server and Aptana (localhost, ubuntu 12.04)

My code looks like this:

```
sys.path.append('/opt/aptana_studio_3/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013032300/pysrc')
import pydevd
...
pydevd.settrace()
```

In Aptana, I added the above directory to PYTHONPATH.

There's no other process (aparently) that runs settrace. There's only me running a single thread on apache WSGI (with mod python).

I don't have firewall on this machine (AFAIK)

1. What is blocking the connection?
2. How does Aptana/pydev receive the event that I started running the code?
3. Is Aptana  supposed to be listening somehow?
4. Am I supposed to tell Aptana to "listen" or to "start a debugging daemon"?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
import sys
    sys.path.append('/vagrant/vagrant_conf/pycharm-debug.egg')
    import pydevd
    pydevd.settrace('192.168.223.8', port=7500, stdoutToServer=True,stderrToServer=True)
```

I use pycharm and I need append pycharm-debug.egg (with Aptana I don't know.
IP is ip of my local, not vagrant (server) IP.

Answer (score 0):

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

there are "Start/stop debugging server" buttons,
and they're initially visible only in debugging perspective.

Answer (score 0):

1. In eclipse (I think it is same as Aptana), go to 
   Window→Perspective→Customize Perspective.

   1. Take 'Action Set Availability' tab and select everything related to PyDev
   2. Take 'Menu Visiblity' tab and check PyDev
   3. Take 'Tool Bar Visibility' and check 'PyDev Debug' and 'PyDev Navigate'.
2. Now go to Window→Perspective→Open Perspective→Other...   and choose Debug
3. Click on the marked button:

[image: debugger button]

4. Then the debugger starts:
   [image: Debugger Console]
5. Now start the server and continue debugging.

The answer to all your question (up to my knowledge):

`pydevd.settrace()` will send debug information to debug server of eclipse which you have started.  By default host will be 'localhost' and port will be '5678'.

You can give more options:

```
pydevd.settrace('localhost/hostname', port=5678, suspend=True, stdoutToServer=False, stderrToServer=False, trace_only_current_thread=True)
```

Comment: @Scott tankxx man